# Where is Altair's Sword?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have already completed the six tombs, but I cannot find the sword anywhere.

Where do I purchase it?

Comment: You don't purchase it.  The location should be on the map.  If its not then you should continue to play through the game until it is on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Revelations, Altair's Sword is the reward for completing the [Assassin Guild Challenges](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin%27s_Creed:_Revelations_Guild_Challenges) and is not related in any way to the six tombs.

Answer (score 0):

In Assassin's Creed Revelations there is only one tomb to be opened after collecting 10 Memoir pages to get the best armor in the game to get Altair's sword you must complete all of the Assassin challenges of the 3 ter allowing you to get the Assassin's Guild weapon which is Altairs sword

The six tombs that you mentioned is Assassin's Creed 2 allowing you to get seals from each tomb then you can head back to the Codex wall turn around head downstairs and place the seals by each statue unlocking a lock to altairs armor the best armor in Assassin's Creed 2

Last but not least is the only tomb in Assassin's Creed Revelations after collecting all 10 memoir pages hidden throughout the city you will unlock a hidden tomb within a building allowing you to do a parkour challenge after that you will jump into a pool of water and find yourself with several golden gilded chests and a tomb that resembles one from Assassin's Creed 2 a little reference to Assassin's Creed 2 to people who have played it